# Having to click twice in my edit gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

OK So I have a web app with a dropdown field, a show button and a gridview that i can edit. Page loads, I choose my dropdown value, page loads fine. When I go to click the edit button however, I have to click it twice in order to be able to edit or cancel (having issues with that also but thats a different issue)
Anyway, I want to be able to have one click on edit to bring up the update/cancel editmode. I'm new to C# Web apps so some insight would be helpful.

Thanks

My ASP

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="styled" 
   OnRowEditing="TaskGridView_RowEditing"
   OnRowCancelingEdit="TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
   OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating"   >
   <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My C#

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    //Set the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
   // BindData();


}

protected void TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    //Reset the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
    Image1.Visible = true;
    Image2.Visible = false;

}

protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)Session["EditDataPage"];

    //Update the values.
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["QuoteNumber"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["ItemNumber"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
   //dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IsComplete"] = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Item"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Descp"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Route"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Unit"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[6].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IG"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[7].Controls[0])).Text;
   // dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["EXTQTY"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[8].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["CSTCD"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[9].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["PCOST"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[10].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["SCOST"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[11].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["ACOST"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[12].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["TCOST"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[13].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["ICOST"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[14].Controls[0])).Text;
  //  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["BIZCODE"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[16].Controls[0])).Text;
 //   dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["DeleteItem"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[17].Controls[0])).Text;

    //Reset the edit index.
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{

    GridView1.DataSource = Session["Sqldatasource1"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the rowediting event you do need to set editindex and then databind.  you need to do it in the other events too.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx

```
GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

your control may disappear if you databind unnecessarily.  make sure you only databind in page_load once.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

My fix for having to click edit twice included ViewState.

My original Load and bind:

```html
AttribGrid.DataSource = dataset;
AttribGrid.DataBind();
ViewState["CurTable"] = dataset;
```

then my subsequent RowEditing.

```html
protected void AttribGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
  AttribGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
  AttribGrid.DataSource = (DataSet)ViewState["CurTable"];
  AttribGrid.DataBind();
  
 }
```

I did have to use EditIndex = newEditIndex.  When I excluded it I still had to click twice. with the above code it was click once as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set the "GridView1.EditIndex" in the Editing or Canceling callback.

```
protected void My_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
// Perform a custom action in here
// But you don't need to set GridView1.EditIndex in here, that would be bad.
}
```

Comment: That seemed to help some. It now stays up rather than disappears but I still have to click edit twice.

Comment: Maybe you don't need "DataBind" in there as well.

Comment: I tried that but it still doesnt seem to work. i have it just like you posted but still have to click twice in order to go to edit mode.

Comment: GridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode.aspx